# Ugly URL keeps showing in address after htacess rewite

Tags: .htaccess

How to keep the pretty URL showing as the final URL after htaccess ReWrite.

I am trying to rewrite effortless_meditation to https://www.peterrussell.com/HMWET/index.php  But the old url keeps showing up in the address bar. Any help appreciated.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^effortless_meditation/?$ https://www.peterrussell.com/HMWET/index.php [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add R flag (redirect) with status 301 and L flag (last):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^effortless_meditation/?$ https://www.peterrussell.com/HMWET/index.php [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried that but still keep getting the ugly URL showing up. Have tried clearing cache.